# Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_42cd_0.MYI'; try to repair it

Tags: ubuntu-server

I recently had an issue of disk space. More than 97% of disk was full. I cleaned the disk space by clearing the log files.
The issue now i am having is the error in my api which says, 
Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_42cd_0.MYI'; try to repair it.
Below is the output of the `df -h` command i executed on the SSH
`root@localhost:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda        24G   16G  6.4G  72% /
devtmpfs        994M  4.0K  994M   1% /dev
none            200M  180K  199M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            996M     0  996M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
overflow        1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /tmp`
 
Other than this, i also tried running the `myisamchk -r profiles.MYI` in order to repair the **.myi** file but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted the issue. It was related with the incorrect join in the query.
I do not understand, if the issue is related with the query then how does it echo the error 
**Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_42cd_0.MYI'; try to repair it**